# cancancan gem passing params to ability

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, cancancan

Am using cancancan and activeadmin gems in my application, in cancan gem i want to pass the params to ability.

controller.rb

```
controller do
    def scoped_collection
      end_of_association_chain.accessible_by(current_ability, params[:project_id]) # passing params
    end
end
```

ability.rb

```
 if ((user.has_role? :LA_Tracker_Manager) && (user.has_application? :LA_Tracker))
      can :manage, Job, project_id: params[:project_id]  # getting the params heree
 end
 if (user.has_role? :LA_Tracker_Analyst)
  can [:read, :update], Job, employee_id: user.employee.id 
 end
```

the above code not working. how to achieve this.

Comment: you don't use // for comments in Ruby, it is #

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I can't think of a situation where it makes sense to pass a param to a CanCanCan ability. Are you trying to acheive something different than `.where(project_id: params[:project_id]).accessible_by(current_ability)`?

Comment: I don't think it's a good practise... the ability roles shouldn't be changed by the request.

Comment: yes where condition also possible, but for another role params[:project_id] wont pass in the action. so for that i need fetch the jobs based on employees. please refer the code
ability.rb
 if ((user.has_role? :LA_Tracker_Manager) && (user.has_application? :LA_Tracker))
      can :manage, Job, project_id: params[:project_id]  # getting the params heree
 end
 if (user.has_role? :LA_Tracker_Analyst)
  can [:read, :update], Job, employee_id: user.employee.id 
 end